# Is it possible to get inbox as feed?

Tags: support, questions

I would like to get my StackOverflow notifications as a feed. Is there an inbox RSS/Atom feed?

Comment: That would require authentication, incidentally

Comment: Ah. That makes sense.

Comment: Presumably this could be done with the SE API.  Not sure if someone has already written such an application.

Comment: Maybe that would be something I could try… heheh.